# What part of the Galerkin method ensures a solution with accurate nodal values?

Tags: finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

I graduated over a year ago as a mechanical/industrial engineer and I've recently been re-studying my last year engineering courses that focused on numerical methods for simulation, including the Finite Element Method.

I've been reading [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-33287-6) which starts off with piecewise linear approximations of functions, introducing:

- **interpolation**: values at the nodes are accurate and values in between are interpolated
- **L<sup>2</sup>-projection** values at the nodes are not accurate but overall function minimizes the least squares criterion, which as I understand is a result of using the scalar product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_I (fg) dx$ .
  *(I assume that using another scalar product instead would produce another solution that satisfies some other criterion)*

**In this instance, I find it easy to understand why one method has accurate nodal values and why the other one doesn't.**

Running through the exercises, I got to solving the following problem using a 1D Galerkin method with linear elements, and using the partition $\{0, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{2}, 1\}$  of $I = [0,1]$  :

On $I=[0,1]$
$-u'' = f$,
$f = 1$  , $u(0) = 0$  , $u(1)=0$

Here are the plotted results:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWmLo.png)

I noticed the nodal values are accurate, but the search space is only that of piecewise linear functions with vanishing endpoints, ie. $V_{h,0}= \{v : v \in C^{0}(I), v|_{I_i} \in P_1(I_i), v(0) = v(L) = 0\}$

Unlike the much simpler case of interpolation, the method does not explicitly force the values at the nodes to be accurate. At least that's the way I understand it. The method only guarantees that the weak form be satisfied by the solution (+BCs).

So **why are the nodal values accurate** ? With such a mesh, I would have expected the nodal values to be offset so that the overall solution better matches the analytical solution (the way L<sup>2</sup> projection does)

Comment: The nodal values can be accurate anyway. Indeed $L^2$ approximation often results in $L^\infty$ approximation depending on the functions you're projecting onto and the function you're starting with. Think about Fourier series of a periodic continuous function (so no Gibbs phenomenon) to get a feel for that.

Comment: What is weird is that it looks like on the rightmost two subintervals, the nodal values appear to be closer than elsewhere.

Comment: Hi @Ian, thanks for your reply. Are you referring to the first part of the post, where I said that $L^{2}$  projection was not accurate at the nodes? I meant that as a generalisation, but I get that a smart choice of function space can result in accurate nodal values :)

Comment: Also the diagram represents the solution to the Poisson problem described above using linear elements - the fact that the nodal values seem closer than anywhere else is precisely what I am interested in. 
I don't get what part of the formulation / method is responsible for accurate nodal values, where for all I know I could have had a solution that *ressembles* an $L^{2}$ approximation of the real solution

Comment: I think it might be an artifact of the fact that the solution to this problem has a fixed concavity everywhere. This seems like a non-generic observation. More generally I would expect your pieces to cross the true function in the middle of the subinterval instead.

Comment: You also might just have an error; it seems to me that if I pull the value at $1/2$ up above the true solution and update the slopes on the neighboring subintervals accordingly (without changing anything on $[0,1/6]$) then the error looks like it would get smaller.

Comment: In view of that thought, let me ask: what test functions did you use, exactly?

Comment: I used $v = \sum_{I} \phi_j$  (whereas my solution was $u = \sum_{I} \xi_i \phi_i$  )

Comment: $\phi_i$  being the linear hat function surrounding node i

Comment: I went through and did your problem by hand (+ a computer for the linear system) and I got the same result as your figure, but with exact numbers; in particular I got $u(1/6)=5/72,u(1/2)=1/8$. This means the FEM solution is *exactly* the interpolant of the true solution $(x-x^2)/2$ at the nodes. This seems like a quirk of this particular problem to me.

Comment: That said, you might try seeing whether the projection of $(x-x^2)/2$ onto the span of $\{ \phi_1,\phi_2 \}$ is the same thing. (Be careful that $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are not orthogonal here.) I think it will turn out that it is *not*, which might give you the desired intuition.

Comment: I calculated the $L^2$  projection of the true solution onto the first subinterval and indeed got a different segment (that intersects with the true solution as one would expect).
I went round and investigated my integration method for the stiffness matrix and load vector but realised something:
Given that the problem has constant coefficients and $f=1$  , the integration is accurate and the computed load vector and stiffness matrix are true values, so I am starting to think that it makes sense that the value at the nodes are the true values.
But something still seems kind of off.